# Prase query string from url javascript

Tags: javascript

my url look like `http://localhost:13562/Student/RefreshStudents?sort=FirstName&sortdir=ASC&page=1`

now i am looking for a function where i will pass url and query string name then that should return value.

so i did it this way but not working.

```
function getQueryVariable(url,variable) {
    var query = url;
    var vars = query.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split('=');
        if (decodeURIComponent(pair[0]) == variable) {
            return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
    }
    console.log('Query variable %s not found', variable);
}
```

calling like this way

```
var x='http://localhost:13562/Student/RefreshStudents?sort=FirstName&sortdir=ASC&page=1'

alert(getQueryVariable(x,'sort'));
alert(getQueryVariable(x,'sortdir'));
alert(getQueryVariable(x,'page'));
```

where i made the mistake?

### EDIT

working code

```
$.urlParam = function(url,name){
    var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(url);
    if (results==null){
       return null;
    }
    else{
       return results[1] || 0;
    }
}

var x='http://localhost:13562/Student/RefreshStudents?sort=FirstName&sortdir=ASC&page=1'

alert($.urlParam(x,'sort'));
alert($.urlParam(x,'sortdir'));
alert($.urlParam(x,'page'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z99L3985/1/

thanks

Comment: What is the output of `getQueryVariable(x,'sort')`? (i.e. what is the wrong)

Comment: Maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery

Comment: Also like this plugin: https://github.com/websanova/js-url

Comment: i use that code but not working. see js fiddle where i test the code https://jsfiddle.net/z99L3985/        what is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps

```
var getUrlVars = function(url){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(decodeURIComponent(hash[0]));
        vars[decodeURIComponent(hash[0])] = decodeURIComponent(hash[1]);
    }
    if(vars[0] == url){
        vars =[];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

Then in your code

```
var params = getUrlVars("http://localhost:13562/Student/RefreshStudents?sort=FirstName&sortdir=ASC&page=1");
console.log(params["sort"]) // FirstName
```

Answer (score 1):

I just get this from somewhere else as well..

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       console.log(vars);
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] === variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
}
```

so far its doing its job. 
    with url: "http://urlhere.com/general_journal?from=01%2F14%2F2016&to=01%2F14%2F2016&per_page=25&page=2"

```
if im going to get the 'page' variable result would be : `2`
console.log(getQueryVariable('page'));
```

my `query` variable is only getting the `search.substring(1)` part of the the url so basically it only gets `from=01%2F14%2F2016&to=01%2F14%2F2016&per_page=25&page=2` part of the url then from that it splits it and then return the value of the string parameter you specified on the function call `getQueryVariable('page')` for example.

Answer (score 1):

may be the following will help

```
   function getUrlVars(url) {
        var vars = {};
        var parts = url.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {

            vars[key] = value;
        });
        return vars;
    }

    var x='http://localhost:13562/Student/RefreshStudents?sort=FirstName&sortdir=ASC&page=1';

    var queryVars = getUrlVars(x);
    alert(queryVars['sort']);
    alert(queryVars['sortdir']);
    alert(queryVars['page']);
```